# Gutenberg - Custom blocks onClick not working?

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to develop a custom block for the Gutenberg editor. I'm trying to display a button and call a web service then redirect the user to the returned URL. Can anyone please help me why my click handler function is not called?

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('brad/border-box', {
    title: 'Simple Box',
    icon: 'smiley',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        content: {type: 'string'},
},

/* This configures how the content and color fields will work, and sets up the necessary elements */

edit: function (props) {
    function updateContent(event) {
        props.setAttributes({content: event.target.value})
    }

    return React.createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        React.createElement(
            "h3",
            null,
            "Simple Box"
        ),
        React.createElement("input", {type: "number", value: props.attributes.content, onChange: updateContent}),
    );
},


save: function (props) {
    function clickHandler(event) {
        alert('clicked')
    }

    return wp.element.createElement(
        "button",
        {style: {padding: '4px', border: '2px solid black'}, onClick: {clickHandler}},
        "Click On Me"
    );
}
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Block Editor's `save()` function doesn't save JS functions to the database to be run on the front end. To run JS on the front end, you need to save it as a separate file and enqueue that file explicitly on the front end.

With that in mind, it would be easiest to rewrite your `save()` function so that instead of trying to call a function directly, it has a specific CSS class you can target.

```
save: function (props) {
    return wp.element.createElement(
        "button",
        {style: {padding: '4px', border: '2px solid black'}, class: 'clicker'},
        "Click On Me"
    );
}
```

Then adjust your function and save it in its own `clicker.js` file:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Add a click handler to just these buttons
        $('button.clicker').on('click', clickHandler);
        // Define the clickHandler function, as before
        function clickHandler(event) {
            alert('clicked')
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Finally, to enqueue the separate JS, edit your PHP file:

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_add_front_end_clicker_script');
function wpse_add_front_end_clicker_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'clicker',
        plugins_url('clicker.js', __FILE__),
        array('jquery'),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'clicker.js' ),
        true
    );
}
```

This will enqueue the file with a jQuery dependency, and timestamp it so if you ever update the JS, it should avoid staying cached. (You may need to tweak some of the above code as I haven't tested it all together, but this should put you on the right path!)

Comment: It's too bad wordpress doesn't alert the dev they're trying to do something that isn't supported.  I imagine a lot of devs familiar with react like myself naturally expected js to work.  Silently failing in this instance feels odd